# find $y^{\prime \prime}$ by implicit differentiation : $2x^3 +5y^3=2$

Tags: calculus

I need the $y^{\prime \prime}$ by implicit differentiation   $2x^3 +5y^3=2$

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I have the first $y^{\prime}$ which is $frac{-2x^2}{5y^2}$

Comment: Great. What happens when you differentiate the implicit equation twice?

Comment: I need the answer without primes. I am trying to differentiate $y^{\prime}$ which is $\frac {2x^2}{5y^2}$

Comment: You could use the quotient rule on $y'$. You will get $y'' = $[something involving $x$ and $y'$], and then you can substitute in what you know $y'$ is to just get something involving $x$ and $y$. You could alternatively differentiate the implicit equation twice and then isolate $y''$ as in the answer below.

Comment: okay I'll try that and will see if matches the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate twice below,

$$6x^2+15y^2y’=0$$
$$12x+30yy’+15y^2y’’=0$$
Then, isolate $y’’$,

$$y’’=-\frac{1}{15y^2}(12x+30yy’)$$

$$=\frac{4}{5y^2}\left(x-\frac{5x^2}{y}\right)$$

where $y’=-\frac{2x^2}{5y^2}$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative:

$6x^2+15y^2 y’=0$ (applied chin rule to $y$)

$y’=\frac{-6x^2}{15y^2}$

Take the derivative one more time:

$\frac{-12x(15y^2)-(30yy’(-6x^2))}{(15y^2)^2}$now replace $y’$ by $y’=\frac{-6x^2}{15y^2}$